# Printing OpenXml Documents in C#

Tags: c#, printing, openxml

I have searched for this but cant find anything to help.

I have a WordprocessingDocument - using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.

Is there a way to print this straight off to a printer, I dont want to save it at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you'll need some sort of program to take the Open XML and translate into how it should be displayed for the printer.  In its raw form its just XML and without the translation the printer won't print it how you would expect.

Comment: Do you know any 3rd party library's that do this?

Comment: @DaveB - No, unfortunately I am not aware of anything that will do what you want.

Comment: Probably a "docx to xps" conversion and then sending the result straight to the printer is the only kind of scenario available. I haven't looked in detail, but here's a program that claims to do this: http://www.convert2xps.com/. It may require interop - not sure.

Comment: @DaveB - try [PowerTools for OpenXML from CodePlex](http://powertools.codeplex.com/)