# Printing Docx without MS Word automation

Tags: c#, printing, docx

I'm trying to perform a mail merge between a docx and the database then print the result to a specific printer and that without any Ms Word automation (that is supposed to run server side)

I think that Open XML SDK can help with the merge but as far as Printing is concerned, I'm clueless.  Any idea ?

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991647/printing-openxml-documents-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question looks quite similar to this one:

[Printing an OOXML document without MS Word installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313503/printing-an-ooxml-document-without-ms-word-installed)

Anyway, I had a similar problem and used Open XML SDK to generate the documents starting from some dotx, but the SDK is not able to render the result on video and/or printer and I had to find a 3rd party library to do that. 
I chosed [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (but there are many other similar products). I could have use it to create the docs, too, but the performances were much better modifying directly the docx.

Comment: That question was from 2008.  I thought some new possibilities could have emerged.  Thanks

Comment: well, I developed my app in december 2010 :-)

Comment: Do you knwo any open source alternative to Aspose ?  I hate being locked by commercial companies.  I experienced this once..  never again :-)

Comment: No, I would have liked to use something open source myself, but wasn't able to find anything, just a lot of commercial libraries

Comment: Sorry for joining a bit late.. Is there any update regarding the open source library for printing word/excel??